# Nested CASE within WHERE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, ssms, where-clause

I am trying to amend a Stored Procedure to use the Account Domicile Override if populated rather than the Account Domicile. The @AccountDomicile pass parameter can either be a single value or pipe separated values, so the below are variations that can be passed:

```
@AccountDomiciles = 'All'
@AccountDomiciles = 'UK'
@AccountDomiciles = '|UK|'
@AccountDomiciles = '|UK|Australia|'
```

Below is what was written by somebody else which doesn't take into account the override.

```
WHERE
    (@AccountDomiciles  = 'All'
    OR @AccountDomiciles = [accounts].[Account Domicile]
    OR @AccountDomiciles LIKE '%|'+[accounts].[Account Domicile]+'|%')
```

This is what i have come up with which seems to work,  but is there a better and shorter way of writing this?

```
WHERE
    (@AccountDomiciles =
        CASE 
            WHEN @AccountDomiciles = 'All' THEN 'All'
            WHEN [accounts].[Account Domicile Override] <> '' AND LEN([accounts].[Account Domicile Override]) > 1
                THEN [accounts].[Account Domicile Override] 
            ELSE [accounts].[Account Domicile]
        END
    OR
    @AccountDomiciles LIKE
        CASE 
            WHEN @AccountDomiciles = 'All' THEN 'All'
            WHEN [accounts].[Account Domicile Override] <> '' AND LEN([accounts].[Account Domicile Override]) > 1
                THEN '%|'+[accounts].[Account Domicile Override]+'|%'
            ELSE '%|'+[accounts].[Account Domicile]+'|%'
        END)
```

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR instead of case expressions in the WHERE clause.

Comment: There's bound to be a better type to use for your parameters than pipe delimited strings - types *designed* to contain multiple values. Rather than this nasty string mangling you're doing, which destroys any chance that the database system will be able to efficiently process your query.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your query is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Fix your schema (or learn it). There should be no reason to need to check for an empty string or a 1 character string in your override column. That should be enforced with constraints (and perhaps a foreign key). Also, just split your argument into a table using a splitter function - no need for this LIKE approach with extra delimiters wrapping.

Comment: Erland discusses your <string as array> approach [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggests something like:

```
WHERE @AccountDomiciles = 'All' OR
      ([accounts].[Account Domicile Override] <> '' AND
       '|' + @AccountDomiciles + '|' LIKE '%|' + [accounts].[Account Domicile Override]  + '|%'
      ) OR
      ([accounts].[Account Domicile Override] = '' AND
       '|' + @AccountDomiciles + '|' LIKE '%|' + [accounts].[Account Domicile]  + '|%'
      )
```

You might need a tweak if the override can be `NULL` rather than the empty string, but this uses the logic in your question.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Annoyingly I don't have control of what goes into the Account Domicile, this is fed elsewhere and inserted as a empty string rather than a NULL.